# AWS KMS Encryption in Angular & Decryption in .NET API

Tags: .net, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I am trying to encrypt a text in Angular using AWS KMS Key and then decrypt the same in the web API. But every time when I am trying to decrypt the Array provided by KMSClint, not getting the actual text.

Using the below code:
Angular

```
const client = new KMSClient({
      region: environment.region,
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: <accessKeyId>,
        secretAccessKey: <secretAccessKey>,
      },
    });
    try {
      const command = new EncryptCommand({
        KeyId: <kmsKeyId>,
        Plaintext: this.form.value['mobileNumber'],
        EncryptionContext: environment.context,
      });
      const response = await client.send(command);
      const cipherData = await response;
      console.log(cipherData.CiphertextBlob);   // sending this | use also the base64 string passed by AWS API Call while encrypting.
```

.NET

```
var client = new AmazonKeyManagementServiceClient("<accessId>"
                    , "<secret>", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

            var encryptionContext = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    {"data", "mobile-number" },
                    {"purpose","test encryption" },
                    {"origin","us-east-1" }
                };

            var decrypetData = await client.DecryptAsync(new DecryptRequest()
            {
                CiphertextBlob = new MemoryStream(array, 0, array.Length),
                EncryptionContext = encryptionContext,
                KeyId = "alias/<keyname>"
            });


            var plainTextfromEncryption = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypetData.Plaintext.ToArray());
```

Every time I am getting a Unicode response in the `plainTextfromEncryption` variable.

While doing the encryption & decryption on the .NET side or Angular side, it is working absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in this line..

```
Plaintext: this.form.value['mobileNumber']
```

We have to send a byte array instead of string

```
Plaintext: new TestEncoder().encode(this.form.value['mobileNumber'])
```